# connect USB keyboard to Arduino using clk and data wires

Tags: arduino-mega, arduino-nano, usb

Edit:
What I'm looking for is some kind of library which could be used with an arduino to read the HID protocol output from the Data+ and Data- cables of the USB.

==========
If I cut the cable of a usb keyboard, plug in power and ground can I use the clk and data wires to read keystrokes into the Arduino? If so any pointers to libraries and schematics?

Simple I instructions? The "for dummies" version?

***EDIT***

Following some of the suggestions below I found this:

https://github.com/julianschuler/USBKeyboard

Which looks like what I want to do, basically hook up the lines into the arduinio and read from the keyboard using the HID protocol in this library.

***EDIT 2***

That doesn't do what I want. Does anyone know how this could be accomplished?

Comment: From what device do you want to read keystrokes? from an USB keyboard?

Comment: yes from the keyboard.

Comment: I think you can do this using an USB Host shield.

Comment: `Which looks like what I want to do` ... no it isn't ... read it again

Comment: If it is possible to make an AVR bit-bang the USB protocol as a device, it may also be possible as a host. Have you tried to find such a library or project?

Comment: @thebusybee I have not found one. That is what I'm asking for.

Comment: OK. It might be because everyone is using a USB host shield. And since the USB protocol is quite complicated, no-one wrote such a low-level library, most probably. -- Is it really not an option to use a non-USB keyboard? Is this a project for many users, or is it just for you in one "incarnation"?

Answer (score 3):

USB doesn't have data and clock lines. It has a pair of data lines with inverted polarity (D+ and D-). The USB protocol is considerably more complex than you seem to imagine.

**However** there is a caveat: some keyboards have the ability to work in *IBM PS/2* mode. For this you will need a USB to PS/2 adaptor (pictured below) and then use the [PS2Keyboard.h](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/PS2Keyboard) library. Your mileage may vary, though, as not all keyboards will work.

[image]

Comment: Any place I can get information on this protocol? I don't want the adapter, I want to plug in the cables directly and manipulate the data.

Comment: I think you don't actually need the adapter. It should just connect the pins of the USB jack to the pins of the PS/2 plug. So you could just directly connect the lines to the Arduino. A very short google search gave some promising results

Comment: These adapters only work if the USB keyboard has a dual controller which understands the PS2 protocol as well as the HID USB protocol. (Most modern keyboards don't) I don't have one of those, and I am looking for a library or method for directly interfacing the HID protocol with an Arduino.

Comment: Then you will need to invest in a usb host shield.